# Prove that there is a natural isomorphism between $V$ and $(V^*)^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Let me just start by saying I'm very very new to this material. I have very little idea what's going on. I've read Wikipedia and a few other sources but this is still very hard for me, so I would much appreciate if someone could help me solve this question, slowly and patiently.

We are given $V$ a vector space over field $F$, $\mathrm{dim}(V)$ is a finite number. Show that there is an isomorphism $i: V \longrightarrow (V^{*})^{*}$, where $V^*$ is the dual space of $V$.

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Given a $v\in V$, and a $\lambda \colon V \to K$, how would you produce a $k\in K$?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you could just do $\lambda(v)=k$

Comment: Right. Now you need to connect the dots to get the map $V\to V^{\ast\ast}$.

Comment: But what is $V^{*^{*}}$??

Comment: The bidual of $V$, the dual of $V^\ast$, the space of all linear maps $V^\ast\to K$.

Comment: let $f \in V^{*^{*}}$ such that $f(\lambda(v)) = \lambda(v)$?

Comment: Ok I think I had a "eureka!" moment. the bidual space of $V$ is all the linear functions from $V^{*}->K$. and $V^{*}$ is the space of all linear functions from $V->K$. So overall, you could say that $V^{*^{*}}$ is the space of all linear functions from $V->k$

Comment: Let $\mathscr{L}(X,Y)$ denote the space of all linear maps $X\to Y$ for vector spaces $X,Y$ over the field $K$. Then $V^\ast = \mathscr{L}(V,K)$, and $(V^{\ast})^\ast = \mathscr{L}(V^\ast, K) \quad (= \mathscr{L}(\mathscr{L}(V,K),K);)$. You want a map $\beta \colon V \to \mathscr{L}(V^\ast,K)$. So, given $v\in V$, what should $\beta(v)$ do to $\lambda\in V^\ast$?

Comment: it should send it to some $k\in K$

Comment: The "No." that originally started my previous comment was in response to your penultimate comment. Your eureka moment still hasn't got you over the line, or maybe you just wrote it up wrong.

Comment: A linear functional acts on a vector.  But you could equally well think of the vector as acting on the linear functional...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The isomorphism you are looking for is given by $\Phi:V\to V^{**}$ by $v\mapsto(\lambda\mapsto\lambda(v))$, i.e. you associate to an element $v$ of $V$ the element of the dual of the dual mapping the element $\lambda$ of $V^*$ (a mapping $\lambda:V\to k$) to $\lambda(v)$.

I know it can look very confusing at first, but you'll get used to it after reading it a couple of times and using it in various exercises and proofs.

Comment: Arguably it becomes less confusing if we use the notation $\langle \lambda, v \rangle = \lambda(v)$.  This notation treats $\lambda$ and $v$ symmetrically, and reminds us that rather than thinking of $\lambda$ as acting on $v$, we can equally well think of $v$ as acting on $\lambda$.

Answer (score 2):

For every vector $v \in V$, you have to produce some $i(v) \in V^{**}$. And this one must be a linear map

$$
i(v) : V^* \longrightarrow \mathbb{K} \ .
$$

So, you have to produce an element of $\mathbb{K}$, for every $\omega \in V^*$. That is

$$
\omega \mapsto i(v)(\omega ) \ .
$$

Now, having as *all* data a linear form $\omega \in V^*$ and a vector $v\in V$, how would you obtain, *in the more natural way*, an element of $\mathbb{K}$?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I know to see this, for finite dimensional vector spaces, is to simply observe that for such, $V \cong V^*$.  This assertion follows as follows:  let $\{e_i\}$, $1 \le i \le \dim V$, be any basis for $V$.  Define elements $\theta_j \in V^*$, $1 \le j \le \dim V$, *via* $\theta_j(e_i) = \delta_{ij}$.  It is easy to see that the $\theta_j$ form a basis for $V^*$, since for any $\theta \in V^*$ and $v \in V$ with $v = \sum \alpha_i e_i$, $\alpha_i \in F$, $\theta(v) = \sum_i \alpha_i \theta(e_i) = \sum_i \alpha_i \sum_j \theta(e_j) \theta_j(e_i)= \sum_j \theta(e_j) \theta_j(\sum_i \alpha_i e_i) = \sum_j \theta(e_j)\theta_j(v)$, whence $\theta = \sum_j \theta(e_j) \theta_j$, so the $\theta_j$ span $V^*$; they are also linearly independent, since $\sum_j \beta_j \theta_j = 0$ yields $0 = \sum_j \beta_j \theta_j(e_i) = \beta_i$ for all $i$.  These remarks show $\dim V^* = \dim V$, since each has a basis of $\dim V$ elements.  Now apply what we have just proved to $V^*$, resulting in $V^{**} \cong V^*$.  But since $V^* \cong V$, we have $V^{**} \cong V$.  ***QED.***

The preceding remarks show $V^{**} \cong V$, but do not provide an explicit isomorphism.  However, taking $f_k \in V^{**}$ dual to the $\theta_j$, i.e. $f_k(\theta_j) = \delta_{kj}$, and then mapping $f_k \leftrightarrow e_k$, probably yields as "natural" an isomorphism as any.

Hope this helps.  Happy New Year,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***